# where is the image capture by RNCamera saved?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I have used RNCamera in my project but I don't know where is it saved in the cache. How can I preview the image and delete the image. The app is taking a lot of cache memory in my android phone.

Comment: did you check images in the gallery?

Comment: the images are not saved in the gallery

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md)

> uri: (string) the path to the image saved on your app's cache directory.

```
 takePicture = async() => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);//print uri for image saved
    }
  };
```

Comment: console.log show the location of cache folder
how to view those images or change the location of the images??

Answer (score 0):

You can check images in the gallery if not you predefined file location.

Please check **takePicture = async function()** from following source which returns data.uri and you have full control to move your file and the display images as well as you can delete.

```
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md
```

Comment: how to define the location of the image saved?
they shows the location of the cache and I cannot find where exactly the images are saved